# Logged object showing properties of base class

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, console.log

Using ES6, I have the following class hierarchy:

class App > extends SuperComponent > extends React.Component

`SuperComponent` has a 'static' property called `PAGES`, defined as follows:

```
class SuperComponent extends React.Component
{
    // constructor + various methods etc.
}

SuperComponent.PAGES = "someValue";
```

When I `console.log` an instance of `App`, I am presented with the `PAGES` property as though it were a property of `App` itself. If I follow the `__proto__` hierarchy, I find that not only does `SuperComponent` have this property, but also its parent `ReactComponent`. Each object seems to contain it.

My understanding is that the property should only exist in `SuperComponent`, accessible from the derived `App` class through the usual prototype lookup. So why is it displayed in all three objects in the hierarchy? Is this a feature of Chrome console output, or am I misunderstanding something?

**EDIT**

It seems this behavior occurs when I log the `App` class from within its constructor. Logging it outside of this produces the expected output.

Log from outside `App` constructor: https://s30.postimg.org/w3afaey0h/Main_Dir_Log.png

Log from within `App` constructor: https://s30.postimg.org/546kf9bjl/Constructor_Log.png

Is this due to to the temporary process of constructing the instance of `App`?

Comment: Your understanding is right.

Comment: Javascript doesnt have classes. It's prototypical inheritence underneath, really. That's why you can do something like foo.toString(), even though foo doesnt own toString itself. Chrome console shows all properties

Comment: If app extends super extends react, and you define a static property on super, I would expect app and super to have the property, but not React. I can't replicate what you are describing, that is, when you define a property on the "middle/Super" class the "child/App" has it (expected) but also the "grand-parent/React"? (unexpected, can't reproduce)

Comment: @chiliNUT App should have access to the property through its prototype, but not contain the property itself since it's a'static' property of super. I will post a screenshot tomorrow to clarify what I'm seeing

Comment: OP updated with screens